# How to sync loved songs on last.fm with songs in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

I would like sync my loved songs on last.fm with the corresponding songs in Rhythmbox by giving them a particular rating in Rhythmbox. How can I do this?

This [is possible for other players](http://www.last.fm/help/faq?category=93#504).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using [rb-mergeplays](https://github.com/lachlan-00/rb-mergeplays) by [lachlan](https://github.com/lachlan-00). To give your loved songs on Last.fm five stars (in rating) in Rhythmbox do as follows:

- Download [lastexport.py](https://github.com/lachlan-00/rb-mergeplays/blob/master/lastexport.py) and [rate5loved.py](https://github.com/lachlan-00/rb-mergeplays/blob/master/rate5loved.py)
- Then do as the [README](https://github.com/lachlan-00/rb-mergeplays/blob/master/README) says:

  > - Pull your loved tracks with lastexport:
  >
  >   ```
  >   python ./lastexport.py -u your_lastfm_username -t loved -o loved.txt
  >   ```
  > - Merge with database:
  >
  >   ```
  >   python ./rate5loved.py loved.txt
  >   ```

  Note that you need to replace `your_lastfm_username` with your Last.fm user name. Also note that you need to `cd` to the directory where the scripts are before you execute them.

Comment: While this works, it requires manual intervention. Any time you 'love' a new song on last.fm that is in your local library, you will have to re-export/import the ratings for all songs. Hopefully someone has filed a feature request to make syncing local ratings and last.fm 'loved' songs automatic in Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot do this. The last.fm/libre.fm plug-in in Rhythmbox doesn't really know anything about what songs you have 'loved' on last.fm, or whether they relate to any songs in your local Rhythmbox library at all.

It would take a significant amount of development work I think, to implement this feature, and get it right. You should file a bug against upstream Rhythmbox though, at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=rhythmbox .

Comment: It turns out [it is possible](http://askubuntu.com/a/220834/19490).

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple Rhythmbox plugin which gets loved songs from last.fm and mark them in Rhythmbox with a five star rating:

https://github.com/bartensud/RhythmboxPlugin-SyncLovedTracksFromLastFM

You can manually import the loved songs of any last.fm user.

Full disclosure: I created this Rhythmbox plugin.